# Struggling with XSLT processing of nested elements

Tags: html, xslt, nested

I am trying to process some XML that has nested elements into HTML where each processed element is within  tags so that I can show and hide divs using JavaScript based on the user pressing a Next link.  I am having problems because the  tag for the parent is being placed after the  for the 2 children.  This is causing an issue because I cannot hide the parent to show the children.

here is the XML snippet I am starting with:

```
<mainProcedure>
   <proceduralStep id="pstp1">
      <para>Some text to display 1</para>
   </proceduralStep>
   <proceduralStep id="pstp2">
      <note>Warning Note to display</note>
      <para>Some text to display 2</para>
      <proceduralStep id="pstp21">
         <para>Nested procedural step 1</para>
      </proceduralStep>
      <proceduralStep id="pstp22">
         <para>Nested procedural step 2</para>
      </proceduralStep>
   </proceduralStep>
   <proceduralStep id="pstp3">
      <para>Some text to display 3</para>
   </proceduralStep>
</mainProcedural>
```

The  can be nested.  The way my current XSLT is processing this is that the  tag for  is placed after the closing  for .  I believe I need to flatten this structure when I output so the JavaScript showing and hiding of  tags works properly.  So instead of having:

```
<div id="pstp1">  Some text to display 1 
   NEXT (embeds JS to hide pstp1 and show pstp2)   
</div>
<div id="pstp2"> 
   NOTE: Warning Note to display
   Some text to display 1
      NEXT (embeds JS to hide pstp2 and show pstp21)   
   <div id="pstp21>Nested procedural step 1
      NEXT (embeds JS to hide pstp21 and show pstp22)   
   </div>
   <div id="pstp22>Nested procedural step 2
      NEXT (embeds JS to hid pstp22 and show pstp3)
   </div>
</div>
<div id="pstp3"> Some test to display 3 </div>
```

I believe in order to the show and hide div to work properly I need to flattened the output to:

```
<div id="pstp1">  
   Some text to display 1 
   NEXT (embeds JS to hide pstp1 and show pstp2)   
</div>
<div id="pstp2"> 
   NOTE: Warning Note to display
   Some text to display 1
   NEXT (embeds JS to hide pstp2 and show pstp21)   
</div>
<div id="pstp21>
   Nested procedural step 1
   NEXT (embeds JS to hide pstp21 and show pstp22)   
</div>
<div id="pstp22>
   Nested procedural step 2
   NEXT (embeds JS to hid pstp22 and show pstp3)
</div>
<div id="pstp3"> Some test to display 3 </div>
```

I cannot figure out how to do this.  I have an  in my XSLT so then this is invoked on the second  element, the  for the second  element is showing up after the processing of the nested  elements.

Here is the current XSLT template used to process the  element.  Please note that this is a work in progress and I may have complicated something that was not necessary.  If there are any questions on the template and why I did something, please let me know.

```
<xsl:template match="proceduralStep">
    <xsl:choose>
       <!--  See if there is a child proceduralStep (or a nested proceduralStep) -->
       <xsl:when test="child::proceduralStep">
          <!-- procedrualStep contains a nested proceduralStep, count the precdeing siblings to help with numbering of steps -->
          <xsl:variable name="stepCounter" select="count(preceding-sibling::proceduralStep)+1" />
          <xsl:variable name="step_id" select="./@id" />              
          <xsl:variable name="nextRefId" select="child::proceduralStep/@id" />

          <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="$stepCounter = 1">
                <div id="{$step_id}" style="display: block;">
                   Step <xsl:value-of select="$stepCounter" />
                   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                   <xsl:apply-templates /> 
                   <br/>
                   <div>
                      <a href="#{$nextRefId}" onclick="show_hide_div('{$step_id}','{$nextRefId}')">Next</a><br/>
                   </div>              
                </div>                
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <div id="{$step_id}" style="display: none;">
                      Step <xsl:value-of select="$stepCounter" />
                      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:apply-templates />
                 </div>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>

       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
          <!-- <proceduralStep> element does not have any nested <proceduralStep> elements  -->

          <!-- Count the number of preceding <proceduralStep> elements  -->
          <xsl:variable name="stepCounter" select="count(preceding-sibling::proceduralStep)+1"/> 

          <!-- Get the current <proceduralStep> element's id  -->                     
          <xsl:variable name="step_id" select="./@id"/>

          <!-- Since the current <proceduralStep> does not have any children, get the following <proceduralStep> sibling id -->
          <xsl:variable name="nextRefId" select="following-sibling::proceduralStep/@id"/>

          <xsl:choose>
             <!-- If this is the first <proceduralStep> element create the <div>  -->
             <xsl:when test="$stepCounter = 1">

                <!-- first time encountering a step, check to see if it is the first nested <proceduralStep> -->
                <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="parent::proceduralStep">
                      <!-- add the Next button before we output the <proceduralStep> -->
                      <div>
                         <xsl:variable name="parentProcStepId" select="parent::proceduralStep/@id" />
                         <p>parentProcStepID: <xsl:value-of select="$parentProcStepId" /> </p>
                         <a href="#{$step_id}" onclick="show_hide_div('{$parentProcStepId}','{$step_id}')">Next</a><br/>
                      </div>

                      <div id="{$step_id}" style="display: none;">
                         Step <xsl:value-of select="$stepCounter" />
                         <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                         <xsl:apply-templates />
                         <br/>
                         <div>
                            <a href="#{$nextRefId}" onclick="show_hide_div('{$step_id}','{$nextRefId}')">Next</a><br/>
                         </div>
                      </div>      
                   </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:otherwise>
                      <div id="{$step_id}" style="display: block;">
                         Step <xsl:value-of select="$stepCounter" />
                         <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                         <xsl:apply-templates />
                         <br/>

                         <div>
                            <a href="#{$nextRefId}" onclick="show_hide_div('{$step_id}','{$nextRefId}')">Next</a><br/>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>


             </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                 <!-- do nothing -->
             </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>      
       </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Any idea how to help get this to work?

Thank you

Comment: Please show your entire XSLT stylesheet - otherwise we can only guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="proceduralStep"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="proceduralStep">
    <div id="{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="note | para"/>
        <br/>   
        <xsl:text>NEXT( ... )</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="proceduralStep"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
    <xsl:text>NOTE: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: so the select ="note | para" does a selective "apply-templates".  Meaning the nested proceduralSteps won't be picked up by that apply-templates ?

Comment: @user3629259 Yes, that is correct. The apply-templates that selects the nested proceduralSteps is outside the div element, thus the result is flat.

Comment: Thank you.  My XSLT and XML are a bit complex.  I made the changes you suggested in my XSLT and it got me a lot further. It works fine until I need to go back up a level (at the end of a nested element).   It is not picking up pstp3 (original post), stops after pstp22.  As I said, my XML and XSLT is pretty complex, I need to keep trying a few more things and I should be there.  I will post again if I run into anything else. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3629259 When traversing the tree, you should never need to go "up". However, the above solution assumes that each proceduralStep is a child of another proceduralStep. If that's not true, the chain will be broken at some point.