# Nested XSLT Templates don't show up nested in the result XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have problems nesting elements using XSLT.

I have read [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974692/struggling-with-xslt-processing-of-nested-elements), this seems the same issue as I have, but I can't get it to work properly.

My XSLT (simplified)

```
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <!--https://www.onenaught.com/posts/23/xslt-tips-for-cleaner-code-and-better-performance#toc-avoid-xslfor-each-use-template-match -->
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.aca.nl/schema/weborder">
          <Session GenerationDate="{format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[Y0001][M01][D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')}" 
            SessionNr=""
            InterfaceRelease="3.0.0"
            SessionId="">
          </Session>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </Root>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="ORDER_DATA">
        <DocumentHeader 
            DocumentNo="{TB_ID}" 
            ExternalRecordId="{TB_ID}" 
            ExternalWebshopId="{CHANNEL_SIGN}" 
            ExternalOrderNo="{TB_ID}" 
            PricesIncludingVat="1" 
            SequenceNumber="22221" 
            ExternalChannelIdentifier="4821476634">

            <CustomerData>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="SELL_TO"/>
            </CustomerData>
        </DocumentHeader> 
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="SELL_TO">
        <SellToData SellToSalutationCode="" 
            SellToFirstName="{FIRSTNAME}"
            SellToMiddleName="*"
            SellToSureName="{LASTNAME}" 
            SellToStreet="{STREET_NO}" 
            SellToPostCode="{ZIP}" 
            SellToHouseNo="" 
            SellToHouseNoAddition="" 
            SellToCity="{CITY}" 
            SellToCountry="{COUNTRY}" 
            SellToPhoneNo="{PHONE_PRIVATE}" 
            SellToEmail="{EMAIL}"> 
        </SellToData>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would expect the SELL_TO item would be rendered between the CustomData-tags but in the outputted file (see result below), the SELL_TO info is rendered after the CustomData-tag even after Documentheader-tag.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xmlns="http://www.aca.nl/schema/weborder">
       <Session GenerationDate="20190927T11:29:01"
                SessionNr=""
                InterfaceRelease="3.0.0"
                SessionId=""
                />
       <DocumentHeader xmlns=""
                       DocumentNo="6130"                 
                       ExternalRecordId="6130"
                       ExternalWebshopId="amde"
                       ExternalOrderNo="6130"                
                       PricesIncludingVat="1"
                       SequenceNumber="22221"
                       ExternalChannelIdentifier="4821476634">
          <CustomerData/>
       </DocumentHeader>

       <SellToData xmlns=""
                   SellToSalutationCode=""
                   SellToFirstName="Max"
                   SellToMiddleName="*"
                   SellToSureName="Mustermann"
                   SellToStreet="Bahnhofsplatz 8"
                   SellToPostCode="66882"
                   SellToHouseNo=""
                   SellToHouseNoAddition=""
                   SellToCity="Ansbach"
                   SellToCountry="DE"
                   SellToPhoneNo="049123456789"
                   SellToEmail="max.mustermann@bahnhof.de"/>
    </Root>
```

Can someone tell what is wrong with my XSLT code?

Update:

The input XML (Part of)

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ORDER_LIST>
        <ORDER xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <ORDER_DATA>
                <ORDER_DATE>2019-09-10</ORDER_DATE>
                <TB_ID>6130</TB_ID>
                <CHANNEL_SIGN>amde</CHANNEL_SIGN>
                <CHANNEL_ID>302-1961532-0413146</CHANNEL_ID>
                <CHANNEL_NO>302-1961532-0413146</CHANNEL_NO>
                <PAID>0</PAID>
                <APPROVED>1</APPROVED>
                <ITEM_COUNT>1</ITEM_COUNT>
                <TOTAL_ITEM_AMOUNT>27.50</TOTAL_ITEM_AMOUNT>
                <DATE_CREATED>2019-09-10T17:36:19</DATE_CREATED>
            </ORDER_DATA>
            <SELL_TO>
                <TB_ID>6744</TB_ID>
                <FIRSTNAME>Max</FIRSTNAME>
                <LASTNAME>Mustermann</LASTNAME>
                <NAME>Max Mustermann</NAME>
                <STREET_NO>Bahnhofsplatz 8</STREET_NO>
                <ZIP>66882</ZIP>
                <CITY>Ansbach</CITY>
                <COUNTRY>DE</COUNTRY>
                <PHONE_PRIVATE>049123456789</PHONE_PRIVATE>
                <PHONE_OFFICE>049 123456789</PHONE_OFFICE>
                <PHONE_MOBILE>+49 123456789</PHONE_MOBILE>
                <EMAIL>max.mustermann@bahnhof.de</EMAIL>
            </SELL_TO>
        </ORDER>
    </ORDER_LIST>
```

Comment: I think you need to show you XML. For your nesting to work, the `SELL_TO` element would need to be a child of `ORDER_DATA`, but your problem suggests it is a sibling. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but ... the advice to avoid using `xsl:for-each` is not a good one. The `xsl:for-each` instruction is an integral part of the XSLT language. Use it whenever it's appropriate and avoid adhering to dogmas.

Comment: @TimC you are right. SELL_TO is NOT a child but a Sibling. I updated the question and included the source XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have read quite some articles on this. There it says for-each is not needed as XSLT processor will handle the looping.

Comment: @Stephan I prefer to form my own opinion (summarized above).

Comment: @michael.hor257k May I will end up using the for-each to get it to work :-)

Comment: Re your question: (1) Please show the expected output. (2) Your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"` - but both `format-dateTime()` and `current-dateTime()` require XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move the (processed results of) `SELL_TO` to the `CustomerData` element, you must do two things:

1. Point your `xsl:apply-templates` instruction to the correct path to the node -
   i.e. change:

   ```
   <CustomerData>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="SELL_TO"/>
   </CustomerData>
   ```

   to:

   ```
   <CustomerData>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../SELL_TO"/>
   </CustomerData>
   ```
2. Remove the `SELL_TO` element from the default processing order by
   adding the following template:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="ORDER">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="ORDER_DATA"/>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

   Otherwise it will be processed twice.

   Alternatively, change the instruction:

   ```
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   ```

   in your main template to:

   ```
   <xsl:apply-templates select="ORDER_LIST/ORDER/ORDER_DATA"/>
   ```

Comment: I have changed the XSLT according to your advice and it works now. Also, you mentioned removing the SELL_TO element from the default processing order in order to avoid processing it twice. Thank you for that as well. In your previous comment, you said you had rather use for-each. How would that apply to this case?

Comment: I did not say that. I said that the advice to avoid using it, regardless of the circumstances, is misguided. In the present case it makes very little difference. In fact, if every ORDER has one ORDER_DATA and one SELL_TO, I would make my template match ORDER (or use `xsl:for-each select="ORDER"`) and place all the processing logic there.

Comment: You are right, you didn't say that. Thank you for the clarification. It's good to read other opinions as well.